# What is the most efficient way to determine if a record with a given property already exists in a Rails database?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to avoid excess DB hits/queries in my rails site. Given an array of URLs, i need to know if a corresponding Website has already been created in my database or not, so that I can create it if needed.

1) The first method selects all the urls  from the array and then queries this smaller set to determine if a given URL has been created

```
urls = ["https://www.google.com/", ... "https://stackoverflow.com"]
my_sites = Website.where url: urls
urls.each_with_index do |url, i|
  this_site = my_sites.find_by url: url
  if this_site == nil
    #do stuff
  end
end
```

2) The second method selects each site from the record individually

```
urls = ["https://www.google.com/", ... "https://stackoverflow.com"]
urls.each_with_index do |url, i|
  this_site = Website.find_by url: url
  if this_site == nil
    #do stuff
  end
end
```

3) Another way? Neither of these seem too efficient, they are both opening a lot of DB connections I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
existing_urls = Website.where(url: urls).pluck(:url)
urls_to_create = urls - existing_urls
urls_to_create.each do |url|
  # create the website, etc
end
```

This will perform a single SQL query to fetch all existing urls, using pluck to avoid instantiating ActiveRecord objects. It then removes that list from the supplied list and then sets up the remaining urls.

P.S. Neither if your options will "open a lot of DB connections." They will however generate a lot of SQL queries. Which is probably what you meant, but wanted to clarify.

Comment: This is great, thank you! I also appreciate the clarification!!

Answer (score 0):

```
urls.each do |url|
   check(url)? false : create_db
end
def create_db
    db create
end
def check ur
    if Website.find_by_url(ur)   
      return true
    else
      return false
end
```

Comment: What does this do?